# Bootstrap 4 HTML Navbar Icon Text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, hamburger-menu

Guys I am trying to get my head around the navbar and I cant for the life of me work this one out

I use the following code to make the navbar

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header"> 
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler-right custom-toggler" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); align-self: auto;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    Menu<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Barr Custom Printing</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Garments <span class="caret"></span></a>         
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="tshirt.html">T-Shirt</a></li>
      <li><a href="sweatshirt.html">Sweatshirt</a></li>
      <li><a href="polo.html">Polo Shirt</a></li>
      <li><a href="hoodies.html">Hoodies</a></li>
      <li><a href="vest.html">Sports Vests</a></li>
      <li><a href="oversize.html">Oversize</a></li>
      <li><a href="organic.html">Organic</a></li>
      <li><a href="sublimation.html">Sublimation</a></li>


    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
     </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
     </nav>
```

This results in the following image on the left
[image: menus]

Any Idea how I get it to look like the one on the right

I have tried mucking about with the CSS but just don't know what to try

Any Help Appreciated

Mark

Comment: Post up your CSS code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here it is. I used flexbox to align items.

just add following html

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header"> 
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler-right custom-toggler" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); align-self: auto;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="text">Menu</span>
  <div class="iconWrapper">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">     </span>

    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </div>

  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Barr Custom Printing</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
```

And the following css :-

```
.custom-toggler {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Live example :-

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67566/

Comment: Thank you my friend youre a star. works great One Question the menu item is there whether you are at full screen or mobile width I only want it to appear when it is on the mobile version

Comment: Ok I have updated the fiddle you can use bootstrap media queries to hide n unhide elements for certain resolutions